# 503 Service Unavailable from manageiq docker container

Tags: docker, http-status-code-503, manageiq

My Manageiq docker container(manageiq/manageiq:fine-1) throws the following error messsage. My OS is windows 10. The ref site is [link](http://manageiq.org/docs/get-started/docker). The environmental variables are all default. But this url https://localhost:8443 throws the below error message all the time.

```
503 Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

Do I have to arrange some settings of manageiq docker container or miss another procedure?

### Updated

Below are contents of evm.log

```
[----] E, [2017-06-01T10:21:19.879539 #229:2b15ca7b9138] ERROR -- : MIQ(MiqServer#start_algorithm_used_swap_percent_lt_value) Not allowing worker [MiqUiWorker] to start since system memory usage has exceeded 60% of swap: Total: [1073737728], Used: [806916096]
[----] I, [2017-06-01T10:21:20.296858 #477:2b15ca7b9138]  INFO -- : MIQ(MiqScheduleWorker::Runner#do_work) Number of scheduled items to be processed: 5.
[----] I, [2017-06-01T10:21:20.367275 #477:2b15ca7b9138]  INFO -- : MIQ(MiqQueue.put) Message id: [149],  id: [], Zone: [default], Role: [], Server: [df317222-46b2-11e7-91b1-0242ac110002], Ident: [generic], Target id: [], Instance id: [], Task id: [], Command: [MiqServer.status_update], Timeout: [600], Priority: [20], State: [ready], Deliver On: [], Data: [], Args: []
```

I think I have to modify the configuration of ManageIQ docker to avoid this error. But i have no idea.

Comment: Do you see any errors here? `/var/www/miq/vmdb/log/evm.log` (enter container with `docker exec container-id bash`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Pls, check my **Updated part**.

Comment: Is it true that there is lot of swap used?

Comment: You are right. I increased the docker memory size and I got no more 503 error code. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Always welcome.